# What is Wakko wearing in the "about the 90s" part of the "Catch Up Song" in the 2020 Animaniacs reboot?

Tags: historical-accuracy, animaniacs

In the first episode of the 2020 *Animaniacs* reboot, the Warner siblings sing a song about what happened between 1996 (when the last episode took place) and 2017 (when the reboot was being written). At one point, they sing "We run out of jokes... to tell about the 90s", while showing them standing in a pond. However, Wakko is wearing something interesting:

[image: screencap of the scene described above]

What is it? It looks like a muzzle, but why would he be wearing it, while Yakko and Dot are wearing typical clothes for the 90s (probably, my knowledge about typical 90s fashion is incomplete at best)?

Comment: As an aside, I'm pretty sure the rest of this screenshot - Yakko and Dot standing in a fountain holding umbrellas - is a reference to the opening credits of *Friends*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It is a "muzzle"

Specifically, I suspect it is a reference to Hannibal Lecter in *The Silence of the Lambs* (1991)

[image]

Comment: Got there just before me. Worth noting that the film came out in 1991, so it fits with the 90s theme of that part of the song.